# MYSQL Database Repair Taking Extremely Long

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a MYSQL MYISAM table which is approximately 7GB in size and has quite a bit of indexes. The table got corrupted yesterday and I have MYSQL repair working for 12+ Hours now.

I would like to know how long does a MYSQL repair actually take for such a table? (I cant exactly get number of rows and exact size at the moment, due to the repair running).

The variables I used are :

```
| myisam_max_sort_file_size | 9223372036853727232  |
| myisam_mmap_size          | 18446744073709551615 |
| myisam_recover_options    | FORCE                |
| myisam_repair_threads     | 1                    |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size   | 268435456
| read_buffer_size     | 67108864 |
| read_only            | OFF      |
| read_rnd_buffer_size | 4194304
```

I was not able to change any of the global variables due to using GODADDY Managed Hosting.

The repair has always been "Repair by sorting" as seen by state.
Is there any other way I can speed up this repair process??

Thank you

Edit:
My memory and CPU usage can be seen in the image below
[image]

I have also tried restoring the database from a 2 day old backup (unto a new database), it also is stuck on "Repair with keycache" on the same table for the past 5 hours.

I have tried mysqlcheck and REPAIR TABLE, not myisamchk, as I cannot access the specific database folder in /var/lib/mysql which gives Permission Denied error. As well as myisamchk empty command gives command not found.

Answer (score 2):

It should take minutes. If it hasn't finished after 12 hours, it probably hung and is never going to finish.

MyISAM hasn't really been maintained in over a decade, and it is quite likely you hit a bug. You might stand a better chance with `myisamchk` if you can get your hands on the raw database files.

Comment: Is there a way I can speed it up, or anything I am doing wrong??
I can get into /var/lib/mysql, but accessing /var/lib/mysql/$DATABASE_NAME gives Permission Denied
Edit: also running myisamchk on the server gives command not found

Comment: What form is that "2 day old backup" in? Is it a mysqldump? A snapshot? Can you get the raw contents of it onto your local machine? You may have more luck with repairing the table locally.

Comment: Its a SQL dump. The issue with that one is that I only want to replace that specific table, which might be difficult. Secondly, the backup was made before the MySQL got corrupted, so I doubt the backup is corrupted?

Comment: Trying to backup the database now just gives the error of the table being corrupt.

Comment: Right, so restore the backup in your local machine, dump just that one table, and restore that one table dump on production server.

Comment: Yes, thats what I am trying to do now, I guess it seems to be the only option. Is there no way to retrieve that 2 days worth of data?

Comment: Only if you can get your hands on the binary replication log or general log for that period to extract the relevant queries. Assuming those logs are even enabled.

Comment: I doubt they are enabled, even if they are, I probably wont be able to access them.
Anyways, trying to import the backup database into my local server on my PC, and its still trying to repair the database, and is taking pretty much the same time so far.

Comment: You might want to consider DISABLING in your config the read_buffer_size and read_rnd_buffer_size to allow defaults to work for you or ask GODADDY to take care of the change.  60M and 4M are both extremely large.  Lead the line with # and a space character.